# How to stich images into a video with resolution larger then 4K using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, gpu, video-processing

I have a folder with images that I've extracted from one video.
The resolution for each image is 5760 X 2880.
All images are in the following format:
out-1.jpg, out-2.jpg , out-3.jpg ..... out-1000.jpg

I tried couple of different ways to stich them:

Using CPU - libx264

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f image2 -s 5760X2880 -start_number 1 -i "AllFrames/out-%d.jpg" -vframes 119 -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p "/AllVideoChunks/Chunk_1.mp4"
```

Worked well but the speed is about X0.05 only.

Using GPU - h264_nvenc

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f image2 -s 4000X2000 -start_number 1 -i "AllFrames/out-%d.jpg" -vframes 119 -vcodec h264_nvenc -gpu  0 -preset slow -b:v 75M  -pix_fmt yuv420p"/AllVideoChunks/Chunk_1.mp4"
```

Working very fast and high quality, but the problem is that I can't use it for images and output bigger then width 4096

Using GPU - hevc_nvenc

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f image2 -s 5760X2880 -start_number 1 -i "AllFrames/out-%d.jpg" -vframes 119 -vcodec hevc_nvenc -gpu  0 -preset slow -b:v 75M  -pix_fmt yuv420p"/AllVideoChunks/Chunk_1.mp4"
```

Working X10 more then the CPU at the speed of X0.5, good quality, but the problem is that I can't use it in normal players (can't play it in Unity)

Is there another video codec that can work on GPU that support more then 4K resolution?
Can I transform the 'hevc_nvenc ' output to 'h264' on GPU in higher resolution? should I do this transformation on CPU?

Comment: **5760 X 2880** is not a normal video resolution. Why not resize into acceptable 4K broadcast resolution? Is there any text in video that is unreadable at 4k but yet is readable when at 5K? Or maybe you're just focused on the number **5760** because that is what is provided (and you don't care about realism, _eg:_ what chip in a display  device is wanting input video width of 5670 pixels? Photo resolution is not always appropriate for video resolution. NASA can make 10K photos (stitched) but they still showcase as 1K to 4K videos.

Comment: PS: I was watching this Youtube video: [You Don't See in 4K](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxNBiAV4UnM) and remembered your question. See if watching the summary (at time `16mins + 16sec`) finally convinces you to use realistic **broadcast numbers** (video decoding hardware are optimized to handle certain numbers). _Eg:_ in FFmpeg try to output a video with a width or height that does not divide by 2 into a result of whole number. If it becomes a fraction, FFmpeg will give an error. Why? Because such numbers cause scaling issues at broadcast time to fit within accepted display ratios etc...

Comment: I'm using this video inside an app running on VR, so my display only shows a fraction from the whole video. therefore I'm now watching the max resolution at a given time, and in this case I think there is a big different in the quality using 5.7K vs 4K. What do you think about it consider VR (Quest 2) scenario

Comment: I don't use Occulus / Quest. When I used 3D modelling software in the past, it allowed different maps on different Faces of the object. So a cube could have 6 unique maps. If you're using a cube inside VR then consider breaking up the video into smaller sizes then use each file as a face's map. If you got a sphere for mapping then good luck with your 3D mapping optimization research.